# Firefox weird issue

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, firefox, onclick, html-table

Only on Firefox do I get this error:

> Element referenced by ID/NAME in the global scope. Use W3C standard document.getElementById() instead.

```
if (c.checked == 1)

GFPart...vitate= (line 17)

TypeError: c is null

if (c.checked == 1)
```

My Javascript look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function SavePartners() {
        var poz = '@ViewBag.Activity';
        var rowCount = dataTable.rows.length;
        var ala0 = "";
        for (var i = 1; i < rowCount; i++) {
            var c = document.getElementById("chkpart" + i);
            if (c.checked == 1)
                ala0 += dataTable.rows[i].cells[1].innerText + "^";
            var ala = ala0.substring(0, ala0.length - 1);
        }
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("TPartners")',
        data: { pozActivitate: poz, listapart: ala },
        dataType: "Json",
        type: "POST",
        error: function () {
            alert("Error");
        },
        success: function (data) {
            window.close();
        }
    });
}
```

My HTML look like this (its a table with 2 columns, 1 with Checkbox and 2 with the Name of the partner)

```
        <tr>
            <td style="border-left: none;">
                @if (listaDeTest.Activity!= 0)
                {
                    string x = (from a in listaDeTest.PartenerName
                                where a == s
                                select a).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (x == null)
                    {
                    <input type="checkbox" name="chkpart @i" />
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    <input type="checkbox" name="chkpart @i"  checked="checked"/>                         
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    <input type="checkbox" name="chkpart @i" />
                }
            </td>
            <td>
                <p style="margin-left: 5px;">@s</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

....
at then end a have a button with onclick function.
Any ideas what might be? Because in IE works perfectly. Thanks in advance

Comment: maybe in your <input> add <input id="chkpart@i" type=...>

Comment: Spaces are not allowed in element "name" or "id" attributes.

Comment: @MikeThunder ??  I don't understand. The fact is that if `getElementById()` returns `null` it means there's no element with the "id" you passed it.

Comment: even if my code looks like this: <input id="chkpart" type="checkbox" name="chk 1"> I get the same error

Comment: Use a - instead of a space in your names.

Comment: Yes, it works! Problem solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internet Explorer and Chrome automatically make global variables for DOM elements with "id" values. Firefox doesn't, because no standard says it should (and it's a goofy idea anyway).

Thus, in Internet Explorer, having an HTML tag on the page like this:

```
<div id='container'>
   ...
</div>
```

means that you've also got a global variable (a `window` property) called "container", with its value being a reference to the DOM element for that `<div>`.  In Firefox, you don't.  You have to call

```
var container = document.getElementById('container');
```

to get a reference to the DOM element.

It's not clear in your code what reference Firefox is complaining about; I suspect it's "dataTable", which I'm guessing is the id of the `<table>`.  You didn't post that however so I'm not sure.

*edit* — oh, and another thing: Internet Explorer, for reasons unknown, returns elements from the `.getElementById()` call based on element **name**.   That erroneous behavior is not copied by Firefox or other browsers. Your input elements have a "name" attribute but no "id".

Comment: yup, I passed the first problem (the one with document.getElementById() ), but now I'm stuck at TypeError: c is null  if (c.checked == 1) .... Even if I select several partners :(

Comment: Well @MikeThunder that just means that the element you're looking for doesn't exist - that is, there's no element whose "id" value is "chkpart22" or whatever.  You should use Firebug or something to determine what "i" is so you can see where the HTML is broken..

Comment: yes it was dataTable > var dataTable = document.getElementById('dataTable');

Comment: @MikeThunder ah I'll update my answer - I just noticed something else

Comment: i changed the name attribute with ID... still no break thru

Answer (score 2):

So what does this code do?

```
var c = document.getElementById("chkpart" + i);
```

It is looking for a id! Now look at your code, what are you missing?

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chkpart @i" />
```

No id! A name attribute is not an id attribute.

Comment: i changed the name attribute with ID... still no break up

Comment: What does the generated markup of the input look like? View source.

Comment: <input id="chkpart 2" type="checkbox"> and so on till id="chkpart 10"

Comment: your id has a space, it is not going to work since ids can not have spaces. Remove the space.

Comment: <input id="chkpart" type="checkbox" name="chk 1"> but same issue

Comment: `<input id="chkpart"` Where is the number?

Comment: I dont know how to declared it because input id="chkpart@i" doesnt work and if its <input id="chkpart @i" ...> put a space

Comment: I recode some but now it doesnt save the selection :( And it doesnt give me any errors.